# GoLang GraphQL fails to tell nil pointer from nil literal

Tags: go, graphql

In my GoLang GraphQL query, I have the following method (takes user id and returns profile data):

```
    "userProfile": &graphql.Field{
        Type: UserProfileType,
        Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
            "uid": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                Type:         graphql.Int,
            },
        },
        Resolve: func(p graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
            uid := p.Args["uid"].(int)
            u, err := db.GetUserProfile(p.Context.Value(handler.CtxId("currentUser")).(int), uid)
            return u, err
        },
    },
```

When user id is invalid `db.GetUserProfile` returns nil pointer `u` and nil error `err`, but GraphQL responds the following:

```
{
"data": { "userProfile": null },
"errors": [
        {
            "message": "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference",
            "locations": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Although when I modify GraphQL code like this (explicit nil check and return literal):

```
...
u, err := db.GetUserProfile(p.Context.Value(handler.CtxId("currentUser")).(int), uid)
if u == nil {
    return nil, err
}
return u, err
```

everything works as expected and GraphQL returns this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "userProfile": null
    }
}
```

How do I manage without explicit checking for nil and teach GraphQL to distinguish nil pointer from nil literal?

Comment: It seems that this is not fixed in go:
https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/issues/178